# Is headquarters plural or singular?

Tags: grammar

Is headquarters plural or singular? Looked at the dictionary and it says we can use plural or singular verb, but I am not sure if everything can be either singular or plural.

Example:

> Is that the new headquarters?
>
> Are these the new headquarters?

When referring to a single building are the two sentences above correct?

Comment: This has an answer on [English.se]  ... https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54031/are-is-headquarters-always-used-as-plural

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "headquarters" can be treated as either singular or plural.

You should try to be consistent. But if the "Headquarters" is a single place (single building, single office etc) then use "is", if there are multiple parts to it then "are" is more likely.

In the given context, if the speaker sees a new building they might say "Is that..."  If they see a campus with many buildings then "Are those"

Comment: Is that the new headquarters? or Is that the new headquarter?

Comment: "Headquarters" always requires the -s ending, whether it is treated as singular or plural. "Headquarter" is not a noun.